# How to bitbake basic c file in yocto with help of local git repo

Tags: c, git, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I want to bitbake recipe of `hello.c` file in yocto using local git repo. Before doing that I have created a recipe but in same folder and used direct path to access that file.

1)C program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

2) `hello.bb` file

```
DESCRIPTION = "Simple helloworld application"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

SRC_URI = "file://myhello.c"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

do_compile() {
    ${CC} myhello.c  -o myhello
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 myhello ${D}${bindir}
}
```

3)path of file

```
sources/meta-mylayer/recipes-examples/
└── myhello
    ├── files
    │   └── myhello.c
    └── hello.bb
```

4) run command

```
$ bitbake myhello
```

This Code is working.

5) Now i have created local git repo

```
cd server/myhello
git init 
Initialized empty Git repository in /server/myhello/.git/
```

6) I have push hello.c file in that git repo

How can I use that file to create my recipe? What changes are needed in `hello.bb` file

Comment: at the moment i don't have the time to write a full blown answer, so this comment must suffice. :-( the usualy technique used for this is [externalsrc](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/current/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#building-software-from-an-external-source) for the development stage, and once you are done the recipe should point its `SRC_URI` to the git repository.

Comment: ok.but can you please help me how to use externalsrc

Comment: What is not clear from the linked documentation?

Comment: INHERIT += "externalsrc"
     EXTERNALSRC_pn-myrecipe = "path-to-your-source-tree" which path we have to give.                                                                                          EXTERNALSRC = "path"
     EXTERNALSRC_BUILD = "path"  which path i should give here.i mean my current folder path or git repo path.

Comment: `path-to-your-source-tree` is probably something like `/home/ganesh/projects/helloworld`. and the ´_BUILD´ shouldn't be necessary to set explicitly.